# getting "version not supported" error while compiling shaders on Mac in OpenGL

Tags: c++, macos, opengl, shader, glfw

I have recently taken up an online tutorial on OpenGL (TheChernoProject) and everything went pretty good until I actually started writing shaders. when I compile my code, it runs, but nothing is displayed on screen, although there should be a red triangle.

I am writing this code on MacOS 10.14.6 in a terminal. I've downloaded both glfw and glew, and am compiling code using a following command:

```
clang++  -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo -lglfw -lglew main.cpp -o main.o
```

I've already tried replacing #version 330 core with #version 440 core, since its the latest my Mac supports, but to no avail.

here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source){
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout<<"failed to compile "<<(type==GL_VERTEX_SHADER?"vertex":"fragment")<<" shader"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<message<<std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader){
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}


int main(void){
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit())return -1;
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
        glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
        glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE );
        glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)return -1;

    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f,-0.5f,
         0.0f, 0.5f,
         0.5f,-0.5f
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1,&buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    std::string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string vertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "   gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For all we know you didn't request a Core context.  Edit in a [mcve].  Feel free to use [this](https://github.com/genpfault/glfw-mcve-base/blob/master/src/main.cpp) as a base.

Comment: [here](https://pastebin.com/vvm1m7FU) is full code if you want to check it out. I have requested core context using your base. now I am getting no errors, but I am still seeing no triangle. [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=71BLZwRGUJE&list=PLlrATfBNZ98foTJPJ_Ev03o2oq3-GGOS2&index=7) is the video I am basing my code on. I've followed it and written everything as is in the video but it still doesn't work. could just be a typo I can't really see

Comment: theoretically speaking, my full code IS a minimal reproducible example. ill edit my question shortly

Comment: "I've already tried replacing `#version 330 core` with `#version 440 core`, since its the latest my Mac supports, but to no avail." No, it does not. OSX supports at most GL 4.1.

Comment: Core Profile requires the use of a [VAO](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ripi2 has it, you need a [vertex array object (VAO)](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object) bound to render *anything* in a Core context:

```
# Mesa on Linux is about as picky as Apple's OpenGL implementation :)
$ g++ `pkg-config --cflags --libs glfw3 glew` main.cpp
$ MESA_DEBUG=1 ./a.out 
Mesa: User error: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glVertexAttribPointer(no array object bound)
Mesa: User error: GL_INVALID_OPERATION in glDrawArrays(no VAO bound)
```

For example:

```
GLuint vao = 0;
glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
glBindVertexArray( vao );
// glVertexAttribPointer()/glEnableVertexAttribArray()/glDraw*() calls here
```

All together:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

static unsigned int CompileShader(unsigned int type, const std::string& source){
    unsigned int id = glCreateShader(type);
    const char* src = source.c_str();
    glShaderSource(id, 1, &src, nullptr);
    glCompileShader(id);

    int result;
    glGetShaderiv(id, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &result);
    if(!result){
        int length;
        glGetShaderiv(id, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &length);
        char* message = (char*)alloca(length * sizeof(char));
        glGetShaderInfoLog(id, length, &length, message);
        std::cout<<"failed to compile "<<(type==GL_VERTEX_SHADER?"vertex":"fragment")<<" shader"<<std::endl;
        std::cout<<message<<std::endl;
        glDeleteShader(id);
        return 0;
    }

    return id;
}

static unsigned int CreateShader(const std::string& vertexShader, const std::string& fragmentShader){
    unsigned int program = glCreateProgram();
    unsigned int vs = CompileShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER, vertexShader);
    unsigned int fs = CompileShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, fragmentShader);

    glAttachShader(program, vs);
    glAttachShader(program, fs);
    glLinkProgram(program);
    glValidateProgram(program);

    glDeleteShader(vs);
    glDeleteShader(fs);

    return program;
}


int main(void){
    GLFWwindow* window;

    if(!glfwInit())return -1;
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3 );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_FORWARD_COMPAT, GLFW_TRUE );
    glfwWindowHint( GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE );

    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window){
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    if(glewInit() != GLEW_OK)return -1;

    float positions[6] = {
        -0.5f,-0.5f,
        0.0f, 0.5f,
        0.5f,-0.5f
    };

    GLuint vao = 0;
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, &vao );
    glBindVertexArray( vao );

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1,&buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);   
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(float), 0);

    std::string fragmentShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) out vec4 color;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "   color = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
        "}\n";

    std::string vertexShader =
        "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout(location = 0) in vec4 position;\n"
        "void main(){\n"
        "   gl_Position = position;\n"
        "}\n";

    unsigned int shader = CreateShader(vertexShader, fragmentShader);
    glUseProgram(shader);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)){

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        glfwPollEvents();
    }
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: after some debugging, I've concluded that the segfault is generated by glCreateVertexArrays(), ill keep working on it

Comment: fixed it: instead glCreateVertexArrays you need to use glGenVertexArrays. would you please mind editing you answer so I can upvote ?

Comment: @mlerp: Done.  Sorry about the oversight, I should have known better :(